# Как осуществить перевод языка в приложении на android в Unity на C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Я пытался сделать, но безуспешно. Всегда один и тот же язык, не хочет меняться. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Translate : MonoBehaviour {

public Text Text;
public string ENG_Version;
public string BEL_Version;
bool eng;
bool bel;

void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    GameObject.Find ("Click Audio").GetComponent <AudioSource> ().Play ();

    switch (gameObject.name) {
    case "ENG":
        eng = true;
        bel = false;
        break;
    case "BEL":
        eng = false;
        bel = true;
        break;
    }
 }


void Update () {
    LocalThisText();
}

void LocalThisText () {
    if (bel == true && eng == false) {
        Text.text = BEL_Version;
    } else if (eng == true && bel == false) {
        Text.text = ENG_Version;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: А объясните, пожалуйста, иерархию. На чём висит этот скрипт? Что вызывает метод OnMouseUpAsButton? Где вы ожидаете изменений языка.

Comment: метод OnMouseUpAsButton вызывает нажатие на клавишу, т.е. когда человек нажимает на кнопку "ENG", то становится английский язык, а если на кнопку "BEL" - белорусский язык. Скрипт прикрепляется к объекту с текстом и к кнопке с названием языка, на который хотят поменять.

Comment: А текст у них случайно не один на обе кнопки?

Comment: Просто не совсем понимаю, как вся эта система должна работать) если на каждой кнопке по такому скрипту. Или это скрипт, который висит на тексте, а уже кнопки вызывают у него метод?

Comment: 1.Ну ок ,ты сравниваешь по gameObject.name, но после клика по кнопке, а значит смене языка, ты имя gameObject.name не меняешь. 2. Не по теме, но это не правильный способ локализации, поищи либы или погугли как реализовать локализацию, а что если будет 50 языков, для всех  case будешь создавать!?